# Not getting error messages in the console when working with discord.py, how do I see what's going wrong?

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to write some applications in discord.py and when something goes wrong in the main code it errors and I head to that part to fix it. However I realized that there are things that have been erroring without giving me any message to work with, how do I go about getting the errors for these?

I noticed that it seems errors in subroutines, such as ones i generate like this:

task = client.loop.create_task(taskname(ctx))

are the ones that fail silently

It would be greatly helpful if someone could tell me how to view the error messages for these "subroutines". I'm not looking for help with my specific code, I just want to know how to see the errors so I can help myself. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you might be looking in the wrong place, as they aren't 'subroutines' they are tasks that you add to the queue (you should read up a bit on asyncio). There is no reason why they would error silently. If they are erroring silently it is because of a different reason.

Comment: Sorry I did mean the tasks, the correct term slipped my mind when I was writing the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a good error handler.

An error handler is a piece of code that outputs the error on a Discord Channel, or the console.
Here is an example below.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, err):
        ' Command on Cooldown '
    if isinstance(err, errors.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(f":stopwatch: Command is on Cooldown for **{err.retry_after:.2f}** seconds.")
        ' Missing Permissions '
    elif isinstance(err, errors.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f":x: You can't use that command.")
        ' Missing Arguments '
    elif isinstance(err, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(f":x: Required arguments aren't passed.")
        ' Command not found '
    elif isinstance(err, errors.CommandNotFound):
        pass
        ' Any Other Error '
    else:
        ss = get(bot.guilds, id=791553406266245121)
        report = get(ss.text_channels, id=791556612715708448)
        embed = discord.Embed(title='An Error has occurred', description=f'Error: \n `{err}`', timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, color=242424)
        await report.send(embed=embed)
        print(err)
```

But if you're using a Cog it's slightly different.
Example Below.

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, err):
            ' Command on Cooldown '
        if isinstance(err, errors.CommandOnCooldown):
            await ctx.send(f":stopwatch: Command is on Cooldown for **{err.retry_after:.2f}** seconds.")
            ' Missing Permissions '
        elif isinstance(err, errors.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send(f":x: You can't use that command.")
            ' Missing Arguments '
        elif isinstance(err, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await ctx.send(f":x: Required arguments aren't passed.")
            ' Command not found '
        elif isinstance(err, errors.CommandNotFound):
            pass
            ' Any Other Error '
        else:
            ss = get(self.bot.guilds, id=791553406266245121)
            report = get(ss.text_channels, id=791556612715708448)
            embed = discord.Embed(title='An Error has occurred', description=f'Error: \n `{err}`', timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, color=242424)
            await report.send(embed=embed)
            print(err)
```

I hoped this solved your problem Have a nice day!

Comment: I don't think it solves my exact problem but it helps me in another way so thank you!

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: Sorry I was off the website for a while. I think what you showed me requires the programmer to account for all the possible errors with cases, but I was wondering if it's possible to just make it show any possible exception at all

Comment: You can make it so if there are any errors at all, you can send a message saying that there was an error, and log the error in a channel and the console.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, but how would I do that in code? I dont mind either in a channel or console as long as I can see it

Comment: The Else argument shows how you can do it.

Comment: Oh okay thank you, it was chopped off on my screen.